# jQuery variable-setting for regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This logs the values of each of 10 `textarea` elements as expected:

```
$('.container').each(function() {

    var textA = $('textarea', this).val();
    console.log(textA)

});
```

This regex works fine in the console:

```
"https://hi.com/hey junk nothing https://hi.com/there".match(/https:\/\/hi\.com\/[A-Za-z_]{1,15}/ig);
```

I get back: `["https://hi.com/hey", "https://hi.com/there"]`

But when I try this:

```
$('.container').each(function() {

    var textA = $('textarea', this).val();
    var matches = textA.match(/https:\/\/hi\.com\/[A-Za-z_]{1,15}/ig);
    console.log(matches)

});
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

Why `undefined`? Is it because the `Type` of what is coming in to `match` hasn't been declared properly? If so, how should I declare so that it can be 'seen'?

Comment: $('textarea', this).val().trim()

Comment: @stribizhev how this would prevent `textA` to be undefined ?

Comment: @bahmait, you should check that in each loop `$('textarea', this).val();` return something. maybe there is a `.container` that do not contains a `textarea`

Comment: My guess is that you have some `.container` with not texterea in it, returning this error. Here the same problem in a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jvmmxrb1/

Comment: Of course: that's it -- I was focused only on the relevant containers. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question: you need to check if `textarea` is present in the `.container`. You can check it with `.length > 0`:

```js
$('.container').each(function() {

    var textArea = $('textarea', this);    // Changed here
    if (textArea.length > 0) {             // and here
        var textA = textArea.val();
        var matches = textA.match(/https:\/\/hi\.com\/[A-Za-z_]{1,15}/ig);
        console.log(matches);
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<textarea name="mytextarea" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
https://hi.com/new-url
More
  lines
      https://hi.com/last-url
    </textarea>        
</div>

<div class="container">
  Empty one with no textarea
</div>
```